# Rails, def or constant to symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, constants, cancan

In my `application_controller.rb` I have this code:

```
def current_resource
   if admin_signed_in?
     :admin
   elsif partner_signed_in?
     :partner
   end
end
```

Now I want to pass this `def` to child controllers like this:

```
authorize_resource current_resource
```

However it throws me an error. `undefined local variable or method`current_resource'`

How I can pass this `current_resource` to its child controllers as symbol.

That is how I call it inside controller:

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
     authorize_resource current_resource
end
```

`current_resource` is inside `application_controller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
 authorize_resource current_resource
end
```

will be executed during `PageController` class loading, not during request handling. So you can't call `admin_signed_in?` and `partner_signed_in?` then. Also I don't know why are you trying to call authorize_resource with argument, because it doesn't get arguments, check [cancancan source](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb).

I think you have misunderstood how cancan filters and abilities work. You shouldn't pass `User` model to the filter. User type should be checked in Ability class and based on that, proper permissions should be selected. In your controller (btw. it should be `PagesController`) you only load resources and authorize them, ie.:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  load_resource
  authorize_resource
  # or just load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

You can customize how resources will be loaded and authorized. Please read [this](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions) about authorizing controller actions and [those examples](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Controller-Authorization-Example). And also please read [this](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities) about defining abilities.

Comment: You mean I just need to call `authorize_reource` without any models?

Comment: Thank you! I was fighting with this TWO F*cough*ing days.

Comment: Yes, `authorize_resource` is a method that should be called without any arguments. It creates before filter which calls authorize! method with arguments based on your controller name. More about this [here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions#authorize_resource).

I'm glad that my answer has helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempted to invoke an instance method on the class. You cannot do this.

If you want to invoke the method without an instance, you need to declare it on `self`:

```
def self.current_resource
   if admin_signed_in?
     :admin
   elsif partner_signed_in?
     :partner
   end
end
```

This will *still* likely not work, unless each of the methods used inside that method are *also* declared as class-level methods.

Comment: NOw it says `undefined method `admin_signed_in?' `. Even If I generated them with Devise and installed it.

Comment: To make access to controller by using `cancancan`, I need to use `authorize_resource :model_name`, but this needs only one model. I have multiple models with different abilities. I thought I could authorize model by looking what model is logged in.